# Changing value in an SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, expression

I'm trying to change the font of the text in my SSRS Report using the SSRS Expression language.

I have a textbox in my report and I set the Value property of it using the SSRS Expression language

```
="hello"
```

Is there a way to make the `hello` literal an underlined string?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to change this in an expression.  You can, however, modify the ReportingServices.css file to change this.

It's normally located here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Styles\
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you set this [using properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181180(SQL.90).aspx). You can't do it via the "expression language" (which is VB.net, BTW).

In your example, the text you have is just the Value property: everything is a property...

Answer (score 0):

In the Text Decoration expression value, you can put =Iif(Me.Value = "hello", "Underline", "None")

Answer (score 0):

create a place holder in that write the expression 
="" & "hello" & ""
And go to place holder properties select the radio button "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles". click ok...
This will work.